# How to format/update invalid data in json using python

Tags: json, python-2.7

My function returns below 'jdata' in json format which is invalid.
I found it has invalid value in "collection_id": ,
How do I set the value of "collection_id" to "" or 0 ,so that I can parse the below json .

```
jdata = 
{
    "status": {
        "state1": "retrying",
        "state2": "poll",

    },
    "conn_info": {
        "version": "0.0",
        "protocol_config": {
            "check_conp": false,
            "max_tunnel_i": 0,
            "collection_id": ,
            "descriptor": 0,
            "signature_key": "",
            "protocol_switching_policy": "udp_only",
            "udp_signaling_config": {
                "polling_t": 0,
                "polling_de": 0,
                "retry_gr": 0,
                "rwindow": 0,
                "status_ra": 0,
                "ud": 0,
                "server": "round_robin",
                "server": []
            }
        }
```

I have used the below code :

```
import json
def test_statusinfo():
    s = jdata

    try:
        decodedinfo = json.loads(s)
        for x in decodedinfo:
            if x == "conn_info":
                return decodedinfo[x]

    except(ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
        LOGGER.info("JSON format error")

Error : JSON format error
```

Comment: You have a function that returns corrupted json? How did that happen?! That's likely where we should focus our attention.

Comment: the standard json parser isn't going to work. You need to fix the text before you give it to the parser. If you know its always exactly `"collection_id": ,` that's bad, you could do vanilla text replacement. Its a hack but fixing broken formatting is always hacky.

Comment: @tdelaney. I verified and found that for some of  the negative test scenarios its always collection_id": ,   For positive test scenario I get valid values. I will try with text replacement for it and then parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the replace command to validate the data and now I am able to parse it.
Added below code before try block  :

```
if s.endswith('"collection_id": '):
    s= s.replace('"collection_id": ','"collection_id": 0')
```